# Angular 6 warnings about multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After I upgraded to Angular 6, the application works fine on the browser, but I get some warnings on the console:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/RxJs/_esm5/internal/util/tryCatch.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\myUser\node_modules\RxJs\_esm5\internal\util\tryCatch.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\myUser\node_modules\RxJs\_esm5\internal\Subscription.js
* C:\Users\myUser\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\util\tryCatch.js
    Used by 38 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\myUser\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\operators\sequenceEqual.js
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

The strange thing is that the `RxJs` directory doesn't exist under `node_modules`, so I cannot understand why I get this error. I deleted `node_modules`, ran `npm cache verify` and `npm install` again, but the problem still occurs. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: could these have been installed with `npm -g`, as global? Try `npm ls -g RxJs` to get a list of all globally installed npm packages that reference RxJs. The error seems to point to  C:\Users\myUser... which is probably not where your project / application folder is. There clearly is a link from some projects to RxJs (caps) and others to rxjs (no caps), even if the folder is technically the same.

Comment: It seems there is no npm package which referencea RxJs:
`$ npm ls -g RxJs
C:\Program Files\nodejs
`-- (empty)`

Comment: What about without the `-g`?

Comment: Same result: `-- (empty)`

Comment: uninstall and reinstall angular? Create a new project and copy your code in? *shots in the dark*